# MySQL error on delete with inner join (1066 Non-Unique ID)

Tags: mysql

Bit of a newbie, attempting to delete rows from two tables.  I'm not sure how to alias - which appears to be my problem - any assistance will be helpful!

```
DELETE emails, emails_bodies
FROM emails, emails_bodies
INNER JOIN emails_bodies ON emails_bodies.email_id = emails.id
WHERE
emails.date_modified < "2013-01-01"
```

Fails with:

```
1066: Not unique table/alias: 'emails_bodies'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra reference to the table `emails_bodies` in your `DELETE` query.  Try this:

```
DELETE emails.*
FROM emails
INNER JOIN emails_bodies ON emails_bodies.email_id = emails.id
WHERE emails.date_modified < "2013-01-01"
```

I also removed one of the tables from the select list, because MySQL does not delete from two different tables in one query.  One option to have this happen would be to set up cascading between a parent table (e.g. `emails`), and a child table (e.g. `emails_bodies`).  Then deleting a record in `emails` would automatically delete foreign key references in `emails_bodies`.

As to why you are getting a `Not unique table/alias` error, MySQL interpreted your query as something along the lines of the following:

```
DELETE emails, emails_bodies
FROM emails
INNER JOIN emails_bodies   -- cross join, since no ON condition given
INNER JOIN emails_bodies ON emails_bodies.email_id = emails.id
WHERE emails.date_modified < "2013-01-01"
```

You were using the same table name twice, without giving each a unique alias.

Comment: Great description.  Will your solution delete rows from both tables or just 'emails'?

Comment: @David I was in such a rush to post that I didn't even notice your select list.  Don't do that.  If you really need to delete from both tables at once look into using cascading deletion with foreign keys.

Comment: Got it, I will just run two delete queries, as I am not sure how to cascade.

Comment: - I need to delete the child rows first, because the select is from a date in the emails header table.  Now I am back to the not unique table/aliax: 'emails_bodies'.  Here is how I modified the query using your example:

DELETE emails_bodies.*
FROM emails_bodies
INNER JOIN emails_bodies ON emails_bodies.email_id = emails.id
WHERE emails.date_modified < "2013-01-01"

Comment: Huh?  Why are joining a table to itself?  I don't think this would ever make any sense in the context of a delete.

Comment: As a newbie, it's hard to communicate the gaps in knowledge.  I'm giving you the solution, although I needed to run two queries as follows:

'code'
SELECT
emails_bodies.email_id
FROM
emails
INNER JOIN emails_bodies ON emails_bodies.email_id = emails.id
WHERE
emails.date_modified < '2013-01-01'
'code'

and

'code'
DELETE emails.*
FROM
emails
WHERE
emails.date_modified < '2013-01-01'
'code'

Cheers, David

Answer (score 0):

Since you joining the same table you have to use `as` to keep table names unique

```
INNER JOIN emails_bodies as emails_bodies_joined
```

And instead of `emails_bodies` use `emails_bodies_joined` in every place where your need your joined table to be